# quotations and parentheses in database causing formatting errors in SQL/PHPExcel

Tags: php, html, excel

I have a web application that takes an open source database and sorts all of the data and allows the user to filter and sort it any way they would like.  The way it works for the filters is that it goes through and selects every unique value for say "county name" and orders it into a radio button/check box so that way they can select any value to filter.  This is where the problem started.  The issue with this, is that it is open source and companies can enter what ever they want to in any field so for instance in the "State" field someone could put "Texas" and another company might put "T3xas."  Or in my specific case that is causing the issues under chemical names some have name such as "(slurry%" with all of these special characters in them.  where this causes issues is when I try and export the data using PHPExcel(the plugin) I get a formatting error which I am almost 100% certain is caused from the parentheses and quotations inside of the user entered data.  Here is some of my code:

So my question is, Is there a way around these errors that I don't know about? is there something wrong with my code?

This is for one of the filter boxes:

```
$db = new PDO("******",      "*****", "*****");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $UniqueOperator = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT CASNumber FROM RegistryMaster WHERE CASNumber NOT LIKE '' ORDER BY CASNumber");
        $UniqueOperator->execute();

        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='checkAllCAS' />Check All<br />";
        //$db->query($UniqueOperator)
        foreach ($UniqueOperator as $row) {
            if(isset($_POST['CASNumber']) && in_array($row['CASNumber'], $_POST['CASNumber'])){
                $checked = "checked = 'yes'";
            }
            else{
                $checked = "";
            }
            //$x++; 

            //$style = ($x%2 == 0)? 'background-color: white;': 'background-color: gray;';

            //echo "<span style='$style' width='100%'>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' class='CASNumber' name='CASNumber[]' value='". trim($row['CASNumber']) ."' ".$checked.">" . trim($row['CASNumber'])."<br>";
            //echo "</span>";
        }
```

And then to create the actual filter I use this:

```
if (isset($_POST['CASNumber'])) {
        $filter_CASNumber = "CASNumber LIKE '%".implode("%' OR CASNumber LIKE '%",$_POST['CASNumber'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_CASNumber = "CASNumber LIKE '%%'";
        }
if (isset($_POST['OperatorName']) || isset($_POST['StateName']) || isset($_POST['CountyName']) || !empty($_POST['StartDate']) || !empty($_POST['EndDate']) || isset($_POST['IngredientName']) || isset($_POST['TradeName']) || isset($_POST['Supplier']) || isset($_POST['CASNumber']) || isset($_POST['Purpose']) || isset($_POST['SortBy'])){
        $previewQuery = "SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM RegistryMaster WHERE (".$filter_operatorName.") AND (".$filter_stateName.") AND (".$filter_countyName.") AND (".$filter_ingredientName.") AND (".$filter_tradeName.") AND (".$filter_supplierName.")  AND (".$filter_CASNumber.") AND (".$filter_Purpose.") AND (".$filter_startDate.") AND (".$filter_endDate.") ".$filter_SortBy."";    
    }
    else {
        $previewQuery = "SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM RegistryMaster";
    }
```

PHPExcel Page, here is where it exports it:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:L1")->getFont()->setBold(true)
                            ->setName('Verdana')
                            ->setSize(10)
                            ->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');

/////////////////////////////////////
//   Creating dynamic filters      //
//   using the users input         //
/////////////////////////////////////
    if (isset($_POST['OperatorName'])) {
        $filter_operatorName = "OperatorName LIKE '%".implode("%' OR OperatorName LIKE '%",$_POST['OperatorName'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_operatorName = "OperatorName LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['StateName'])) {
        $filter_stateName = "StateName LIKE '%".implode("%' OR StateName LIKE '%",$_POST['StateName'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_stateName = "StateName LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['CountyName'])) {
        $filter_countyName = "CountyName LIKE '%".implode("%' OR CountyName LIKE '%",$_POST['CountyName'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_countyName = "CountyName LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['IngredientName'])) {
        $filter_ingredientName = "IngredientName LIKE '%".implode("%' OR IngredientName LIKE '%",$_POST['IngredientName'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_ingredientName = "IngredientName LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['TradeName'])) {
        $filter_tradeName = "TradeName LIKE '%".implode("%' OR TradeName LIKE '%",$_POST['TradeName'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_tradeName = "TradeName LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['Supplier'])) {
        $filter_supplierName = "Supplier LIKE '%".implode("%' OR Supplier LIKE '%",$_POST['Supplier'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_supplierName = "Supplier LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (!empty($_POST['StartDate'])) {
        $filter_startDate = "Expr1 >= '".DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$_POST['StartDate'])->format('Y/m/d')."'";
    }
    else {
        $filter_startDate = "Expr1 >= '2014/01/01'";
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['EndDate'])) {
        $filter_endDate = "Expr1 <= '".DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$_POST['EndDate'])->format('Y/m/d')."'";
    }
    else {
        $filter_endDate = "Expr1 <= '2017/01/01'";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['CASNumber'])) {
        $filter_CASNumber = "CASNumber LIKE '%".implode("%' OR CASNumber LIKE '%",$_POST['CASNumber'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_CASNumber = "CASNumber LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['Purpose'])) {
        $filter_Purpose = "Purpose LIKE '%".implode("%' OR Purpose LIKE '%",$_POST['Purpose'])."%'";    
    }
        else {
            $filter_Purpose = "Purpose LIKE '%%'";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['SortBy'])) {
        $filter_SortBy = "ORDER BY ". $_POST['SortBy']; 
    }
        else {
            $filter_SortBy = "ORDER BY Expr2";
        }
/////////////////////////////////////
//   constructing final query      //
//                                 //
/////////////////////////////////////


if (isset($_POST['OperatorName']) || isset($_POST['StateName']) || isset($_POST['CountyName']) || isset($_POST['IngredientName']) || isset($_POST['TradeName']) || isset($_POST['SupplierName']) || !empty($_POST['StartDate']) || !empty($_POST['EndDate']) || isset($_POST['CASNumber']) || isset($_POST['Purpose']) || isset($_POST['SortBy'])){
        $previewQuery = "SELECT TOP (100000) * FROM RegistryMaster WHERE (".$filter_operatorName.") AND (".$filter_stateName.") AND (".$filter_countyName.") AND (".$filter_ingredientName.") AND (".$filter_tradeName.") AND (".$filter_supplierName.")  AND (".$filter_CASNumber.") AND (".$filter_Purpose.") AND (".$filter_startDate.") AND (".$filter_endDate.") ".$filter_SortBy."";
    }
    else {
        $previewQuery = "SELECT TOP(50000) * FROM RegistryMaster";
    }

        if (!$previewQuery) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
        exit();
        }
$counter = 2;           


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Job Start Date')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Job End Date')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Operator Name')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'State Name')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'County Name')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'Well Name')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'Purpose')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'Ingredient Name')
            ->setCellValue('I1', 'Trade Name')
            ->setCellValue('J1', 'Supplier Name')
            ->setCellValue('K1', 'CAS Number')
            ->setCellValue('L1', 'Percent High Additive');
        foreach ($db->query($previewQuery) as $row) {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.(string)$counter, $row['Expr1'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.(string)$counter, $row['Expr2'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.(string)$counter, $row['OperatorName'])
            ->setCellValue('D'.(string)$counter, $row['StateName'])
            ->setCellValue('E'.(string)$counter, $row['CountyName'])
            ->setCellValue('F'.(string)$counter, $row['WellName'])
            ->setCellValue('G'.(string)$counter, $row['Purpose'])
            ->setCellValue('H'.(string)$counter, $row['IngredientName'])
            ->setCellValue('I'.(string)$counter, $row['TradeName'])
            ->setCellValue('J'.(string)$counter, $row['Supplier'])
            ->setCellValue('K'.(string)$counter, $row['CASNumber'])
            ->setCellValue('L'.(string)$counter, $row['PercentHighAdditive']);
            $counter++;
        };
```

Comment: You say that the problem is when you export to Excel and not when you filter? Where are you trying to export?

Comment: The export is happening on a POST button which calls the PHPExcel page.  I can past the entire Export page as well.

Comment: Can you post the exact error to your question?

Comment: This is the error i get:

    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred translating the query string to UTF-16: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. .' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exportExcel.php:167 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exportExcel.php(167): PDO->query('SELECT TOP (100...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\exportExcel.php on line 167

Comment: also note, I took out the UTF8 setting noted below because it was giving me an error that said it was expecting 2 parameters and getting 3

'$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);'

Answer (score 0):

You can try explicitly setting the values as strings:

```
->setCellValueExplicit('A'.(string)$counter, $row['Expr1'], PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```